# Laravel - database return empty row although there is a record

Tags: sql, database, laravel-5

Currently i'm using laravel to create a application and database, I found that some record in database cannot be select, it will return empty result although there is a record.

The records are in the below image:

[image: here is my query: `]

```
SELECT * FROM assets WHERE assetable_type = 'App\Product';
```

Database results are in the below image:

[image: Database result]

When i select on id or usage field, the result is ok, but when i select on assetable_type, database return me empty result.

The "usage", "assetable_id" and "assetable_type" is nullable, usage is normal but assetable_id and assetable_type return empty row.

Why will it be and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like below:

```
SELECT * FROM assets WHERE assetable_type like TRIM('App\\Product');
```

or like you also can use with \\

```
SELECT * FROM assets WHERE assetable_type='App\\Product';
```

If you want to know more about trim check [here](http://www.w3resource.com/sql/character-functions/trim.php)

**Note:**

```
Escape Sequence Character Represented by Sequence
An ASCII NUL (0x00) character.
\’  A single quote (“’”) character.
\”  A double quote (“””) character.
\b  A backspace character.
\n  A newline (linefeed) character.
\r  A carriage return character.
\t  A tab character.
\Z  ASCII 26 (Control+Z). 
\\  A backslash (“\”) character.
\%  A “%” character. 
\_  A “_” character.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use escape character as below:

```
SELECT * FROM assets WHERE assetable_type = 'App\\Product';
```